# What does `git branch -M` do with a single argument?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I'm trying to upload a local repo to GitHub.  After creating a new repo on the site, GitHub gives the following instructions to execute locally:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/MyOrg/repo-name.git
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
```

When I execute them, I get an error at the `git branch` step:

```
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/MyOrg/repo-name.git
$ git branch -M main
error: refname refs/heads/trunk not found
fatal: Branch rename failed
```

The `-M` flag to `git branch` is a combination of `-m` (move) and `-f` (force) to forcibly rename a branch.  The standard command for this is of the form

```
$ git branch -M <oldbranch> <newbranch>
```

Here, however, GitHub has given me only a single argument.  I assume, because no one involved can be bothered to make clear, that this one argument is `<newbranch>`.

The [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) say only that

> With a -m or -M option, `<oldbranch>` will be renamed to `<newbranch>`. If `<oldbranch>` had a corresponding reflog, it is renamed to match `<newbranch>`, and a reflog entry is created to remember the branch renaming. If `<newbranch>` exists, -M must be used to force the rename to happen.

with no explanation of what happens when `<oldbranch>` is not specified.  I assume that there's some secret algorithm that `git branch` uses to determine what it should use for `<oldbranch>`.  Knowing this would help me figure out what causes the error I get and how to fix it.  Am I allowed to know how `git branch -M` handles a single argument?

**Resolution**

@bk2204 suggests that `git branch` implicitly takes `<oldbranch>` to be the current branch if it's not provided as part of the command.  This makes enough sense to assume, though an authoritative source would still be great.

@phd then suggests several ways of determining the current branch.  In my case:

```
$ git branch --show-current
trunk

$ git rev-parse HEAD
HEAD

$ git symbolic-ref HEAD
refs/heads/trunk
```

Since the error I got trying to follow GitHub's instructions cites `refs/heads/trunk` explicitly, I further assume that `git branch` calls `git symbolic-ref HEAD` in order to determine the current branch.  Again, an authoritative confirmation of this would be awesome.

According to its [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-symbolic-ref), `git symbolic-ref` returns the filepath associated with the symbolic reference "HEAD".

In my case, the returned filepath `refs/heads/trunk` does not exist.  Instead, I have a file `refs/heads/master`:

```
$ ls -A1h refs/heads/
master
origin/
```

Lacking guidance from GitHub, I must assume that this is what they want me to rename "main".  I can do that with `git branch -M` and explicitly supplying it as `<oldbranch>`:

```
$ git branch -M master main
$ ls -A1h refs/heads/
main
origin/
```

After this is done, the command

```
$ git push -u origin main
```

works as intended, and the repo is pushed to GitHub.

Comment: The `-m` and `-M` options to `git branch` were upgrade in Git 2.30 to allow renaming the not-yet-existing current branch name in special situations, such as when you're in a new, empty repository. When there are no commits yet, there cannot be any branch names yet. Nonetheless, Git requires that you be "on" some branch, even if it doesn't exist. There are other ways to rename the nonexistent branch in pre-2.30 Git versions, but the obvious one—`git branch -m`—didn't work until then.

Comment: @torek That's good for context, thanks.  This is not an empty repo, though, it's a bare repo converted from an SVN repo.  It has plenty of commits from the conversion.

Comment: Ah, in that case, it's just a matter of the conversion software not bothering to set the *current* branch name to some existing branch. That would be a (small) bug in whatever conversion software you're using...

Answer (score 2):

`git branch` uses the current branch if no `oldbranch` is specified.  Thus, `git branch -M main` renames the current branch `main`.

In your case, the current branch doesn't exist, probably because you don't have any commits locally.  Once you commit, the branch will exist, and the branch rename will work.

Comment: I see.  I don't have anything to commit, though.  I'm converting an old SVN repo into a repo on GitHub, and I don't want to add anything new in the middle, just upload the SVN repo as-is.  Do you know of another way to make the current branch exist?

Comment: Also, do you know how `git branch` determines what the current branch is, so I can check what it's doing for myself?

Comment: `git status -sb` should show you the current branch.  If you don't have any commits right now, then just wait until later to run `git branch -M main`.

Comment: [`git branch --show-current`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---show-current), `git rev-parse HEAD`, `git symbolic-ref HEAD`

Comment: @BoreaDeitz It's an answer to your question "*do you know how git branch determines what the current branch is…?*"

Comment: @bk2204 I need to do this now.  It's impossible to believe that there's no other way to establish a branch so that I can push a repo to GitHub.

Comment: @phd The three commands give different output.  How does `git branch` choose among them?

Comment: @BoreaDeitz Those "different output" are just different format (branch name or commit ID) and different error codes for the same answer — where does the `HEAD` is pointing to. You use one of these commands in different situations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235386/discussion-between-phd-and-borea-deitz).

Answer (score 0):

basically it renames your current branch to the new branch ,

e.g. Current branch - master (will be renamed to the)
new branch - main

-m
--move
Move/rename a branch, together with its config and reflog.

**-M**
Shortcut for --move --force.

[reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch)

[image]